# Ползунок для выбора времени

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как мне сделать вот такой ползунок, чтобы я мог выбирать месяц, три месяца, год и т. д. Что для этого нужно именно по  JS или jQuery? Или может у кого есть уже похожая тема и вы могли бы мне скинуть или объяснить, чтобы реализовать данный ползунок?

[image: Ползунок]

Comment: В самом простом случае использовать [jqueryui slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вот код вышел: 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel217/aqjezf8h/6/)

```js
$("label")
  .click(function() {
    var nowBox = parseInt(this.htmlFor);
    $("#" + nowBox + "box").prop("checked", false)
    while (nowBox != 1) {
      nowBox--;
      $("#" + nowBox + "box").prop("checked", true)
    }
    nowBox = parseInt(this.htmlFor)
    while (nowBox != 6) {
      nowBox++;
      $("#" + nowBox + "box").prop("checked", false)
    }
  })
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(33, 87, 196);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.line {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 9.5px;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(33, 87, 196);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
}

input:checked+.line,
input:checked+label,
input:checked+.line+label {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="1box" cheked>
<label for="1box">
  <p>box1</p></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="2box">
<div class="line"></div>
<label for="2box">
  <p>box2</p></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="3box">
<div class="line"></div>
<label for="3box">
  <p>box3</p></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="4box">
<div class="line"></div>
<label for="4box">
  <p>box4</p></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="5box">
<div class="line"></div>
<label for="5box">
  <p>box5</p></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="6box">
<div class="line"></div>
<label for="6box">
  <p>box6</p></label>
```

P.S Это можно написать и на js, изменив несколько строк.